# Scrapy Xpath How should I handle missing data between tags in a table?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I'm using python's scrapy to scrape a table off a site, so I've got to use scrapy's Selector xpath to do this. I was thinking about getting all the data contents of the table and then zipping (zip()) it up with the table headers so that in my final data, each of the table's data contents matches to the label that represents it. However, I've noticed that some parts of the table have no values.. as in instead of

```
<td>24</td>
```

it's just

```
<td></td>
```

When I scrape, scrapy will jump over the empty tags and just get the next value. This screws up the way I'm going to zip things up because everything could be shifted by one or more to the left because of the missing value. So.. is there a way to make scrapy's Selector xpath return some kind of Null identifier that something is missing there, so that I can account for missing info? Or perhaps there's a better way to approach my problem in general that prevents this issue from occuring? Thanks!

edit:
The xpath looks something like...

```
Selector(response).xpath("tbody/tr/td/text()").extract()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about this?

```
values = [''.join(td.xpath('.//text()').extract()) for td in Selector(response).xpath('//tbody/tr/td')]
```

explain:

#### ''.join and extract() results

for `<td>123</td>` case: `xpath('//td/text()').extract()` returns [u'123']

for `<td></td>` case: `xpath('//td/text()').extract()` returns []

''.join([u'123']) ==> u'123'

''.join([]) ==> u'' //empty string

#### selector chain

`selector.xpath('//td/text()')` equals `selector.xpath('//td').xpath('.//text()')`

#### selector forloop

```
values = []
for td in s1.xpath('//td'):
    # td is a selector with single element
    # so that it will not return a list with multiple values ['value1', 'value2']
    # selector.xpath('.//text()') just two cases: 
    # 1) []  <td><td>
    # 2) [u'values']  <td>values<td>
    value = ''.join(td.xpath('.//text()').extract()) 
    # returns '' or 'values'
    values.append(value)
```

#### here's my test code

```
s1= Selector(text='<div><span></span><span>232</span><span>haha<span><span></span></div>')

values = [''.join(text.xpath('.//text()').extract()) for text in s1.xpath('//span')]
\# values: ['', u'232', u'haha', '', '']
```

Comment: What is the td in td.xpath referring to? the preceding xpath stuff for "tbody/tr/"? I assumed that, and tried the equivalent with my code and got a list of really long numbers, all of the same value.. so that's not quite right.

Comment: Oh wait, I had a couple typos, so now it works! Sweet! but I only sort of understand why it works.. Care to explain? Thanks!!

Comment: One more quick question.. is there an easy way to or the last element? like say I want to get a from div/span/a and b from div/span/b. I know about the union | but I've been writing out the entire path twice when I use it. Is there something like a div/span/(a|b)?

Comment: I ask this because I'd like to use what you've provided me for a scenario where after tbody/tr, the text I want is located either in td or in th/a, so i think it'll be a little tricky to fit your soln around this problem.

Comment: Solving my question about a|b doesn't really help.. I guess what I'm also kind of asking is.. is there a way to keep the check for null values, but  alos change how the for loop works by having td in the for loop be able to be various things?